# Django form self validation not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

My **urls.py** is something like this :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import ListView, TemplateView

from .models import Dreamreal
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^connection/login/$', views.login),
    url(r'^connection/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 
    'login.html')),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name = 'login')
]
```

My **views.py** is :

```
from .forms import LoginForm
from . import models

def login(request):
username = "not logged in"

if request.POST:
    # GET THE POSTED FORM
    MyLoginForm = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if MyLoginForm.is_valid():
        username = MyLoginForm.cleaned_data['username']
else:
    MyLoginForm = LoginForm()

return render(request, 'loggedin.html', {'username' : username})
```

My **forms.py** is :

```
from django import forms
from .models import Dreamreal

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
username = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput())

# METHOD TO VERIFY IF USER IS IN DB
def clean_message(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
    dbuser = Dreamreal.objects.filter(name = 'username')

    if not dbuser:
        raise forms.ValidationError("User does not exist in our db!")

    return username
```

My **models.py** is :

```
from django.db import models
class Dreamreal(models.Model):
website = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
mail = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
phonenumber = models.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    db_table = 'dreamreal'
```

My **login.html** is :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>LOG IN</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form" action="/connection/login/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div style="max-width: 470px;">
        <center><input type="text" name="username" 
        placeholder="username" style="margin-left: 20%;" required>
        </center>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="max-width: 470px;">
        <center><input type="password" name="password" 
        placeholder="password" style="margin-left: 20%;"></center>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="max-width: 470px;">
        <center><button style = "border:0px; background-color:#4285F4; 
        margin-top:8%; height:35px; width:80%;margin-left:19%;" type = 
        "submit" value = "Login" >
              <strong>Login</strong>
            </button></center>
        </div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

My **loggedin.html** is :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<html>
<head>
<title>{% block title%}{{ username }}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
    You are : <strong>{{ username }}</strong>
{% endblock %}
```

When i am running the code and then entering the name and password in the dield input at /connection/ url, it is redirecting to /connectionlogin/ url but showing valid for all the usernames i am entering in the forms rather it should show only those names which are stored in the database name **Dreamreal**.
Somebody please help!

Comment: Note that Django comes with [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) and forms. It would be better to use these rather than writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

You are validating the `username` field, so you should name your method `clean_username`. Django will only call the `clean_message` field if the form has a field called `message`.

To see any form errors in the template you need to include the form in the context when you call render:

```
return render(request, 'loggedin.html', {'username' : username, 'form': MyLoginForm}
```

And you won't see the errors in the template unless you use `form` in the template. The easiest way to do this is to include `{{ form }}`. If you need to do something more advanced, see the docs on [working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates).

Comment: I did changed the method name to clean_username but now its always showing not logged in. It's not executing the if MyLoginForm.is_valid() statement.

Comment: The check is normally `if request.method == 'POST':`, but I don't think that explains the problem. I can't help you debug this view any further. As I suggested in my comment earlier, it is simpler and more secure to use Django's login view rather than writing your own.

Comment: Can you provide me the more simplified code for this :-) I would appreciate that :-

Comment: I already linked to the [authentication docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views), I'm afraid I can't provide any more code.